# How to move div vertically down using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, class, html

I'm new to CSS and I'd like to move a div section down (pls see attached image below):

[image]

How do I make the div.title "float down" so that it neatly settles to the bottom left corner of the main div (aqua coloured box).

I've tried vertical-align but it doesnt work.

Comment: can u share your code and efforts please

Answer (score 32):

Give margin-top

```
div{margin-top:10px;}
```

Comment: i like this better, position absolute messed up other things for me

Comment: this doesn't work if there are several divs and you want to move only one

Answer (score 9):

You could make your blue `div` `position: relative` and then give the `div.title` `position:absolute;` and `bottom: 0px`

Here is a working demo.. http://jsfiddle.net/gLaG6/

Comment: Would you know how to add a padding to all 4 sides of a table but not each of the individual cells?

Comment: `<table style="margin:XXpx">` ?

Comment: this brakes horizontal centring

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any mention of flexbox in here, so I will illustrate:

> HTML

```
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main">top</div>
   <div class="footer">bottom</div>
 </div>
```

> CSS

```
 .wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   min-height: 100vh;
  }
 .main {
   flex: 1;
 }
 .footer {
  flex: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Good answer, just missing explanation: `flex` property is a shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined. Using just one value equals using `flex-grow`. `flex` property does not *move* a div, as was asked in the question, but will do what OP asked. To really move a div, if there was another div below over which we'll like to jump, use `order: 1` instead of `flex` property.

Answer (score 0):

A standard width space for a standard 16px font is 4px.

Source: http://jkorpela.fi/styles/spaces.html

Answer (score 0):

if div.title is a div then put this:

```css
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: "if div.title is a div" - The selector `div.title` means that it selects *only divs* with the class `title`

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```css
    position to absolute
    width to 100%
    height to 100px
    bottom to 10
    background-color: blue
```

This can help actually move the div to the bottom. Just modify accordingly.